# Android: dropdown spinner title

Tags: android

Android 4.0.3

I have a simple dropdown spinner. By default title of spinner is the first item in list, but i whant to set my text. How to do that ? android: promt - doesnt work

Comment: You should post your XML, `android:prompt` definitely works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to change the text of the spinner when it's closed right?
Well, android:prompt is not intended to do this. It only sets a header to the spinner. You can't change the text displayed on the closed spinner by default. Android takes the first item of the spinner and displys that. So if you don't want that then you'll have to modify the adapter.